# Add to file data in data structure and compare file data in python

Tags: python-3.x

i have two file which have  transaction information like order no, item code , item price ,total. both file have same data. I need to fetch both file data and insert into a data-structure. after that we need to compare both file data and check any mismatch in both file or both file have same data.check on basis of order no, and item code and total no of item per order.
Thanks